# proxy server configuration using NetworkManager nmcli

Tags: proxy, networkmanager

I need to set proxy server URL on my machine with NetworkManager commands only. I can't install other tools. The device runs MbedLinux (linux embedded distro).

Q: How do I configure the proxy server using NetworkManager nmcli commands?

I found [these NetworkManager proxy settings](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/settings-proxy.html), but I have no idea how to set these settings.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: The device runs MbedLinux (linux embedded distro)

Answer (score 1):

This is extracted from my own [gist](https://gist.github.com/signed-log/2568d978b325586b913f215745a1e65f)

---

Create a Proxy Auto-Config File

- [Example](https://findproxyforurl.com/example-pac-file/)
- [API Reference](https://findproxyforurl.com/pac-functions/)

For a basic, send-all, but local, scenario, we'll take the following as an example :

```js
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    // Exclude localhost
    if (
        isPlainHostName(host) ||
        isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0")
    )
        return "DIRECT";
    else return "PROXY 123.123.123.123:8080";
}
```

Save that into a known location with a file extension of `.pac` for better reference

#### CLI

##### Step 4

Run :

```bash
    nmcli connection edit <wifi-network-name>
```

This will pop you into the NetworkManager editor shell

##### Step 5

We'll need to modify both the `proxy.method` and `proxy.pac-script` parameters

First, `proxy.method` needs to be set to `auto`, to allow for a PAC script

```bash
    set proxy.method auto
```

##### Step 6

Finally, `proxy.pac-script` has to be set

The format is `file://<Absolute Path to the file>`

For example : `file:///home/example/example.pac` (note the `///` that represent an absolute path)

```bash
    set proxy.pac-script file:///home/example/example.pac
```